# How to implement promise type scenario using rxjs and redux observable?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I have a scenario where after saving form data, user will see a notification in react component. I don't want to save the data in redux store. How to do this using redux observable and react?

Comment: I assume  that the solution would depend mainly on the react component that you are using for notifications. Example: `react-toastify` exports a function `toast` that allows to show notifications via a side effect directly inside your epic (efter saving the form data). If you need a more specific answer just add some more info about your problem (the relevant part of your epic and your notifications react component)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking how to turn a promise into an observable, you can use the `from` operator.  In your scenario, you can try the code below.

```
const saveObservable$ = from(httpSvc.save(reqBody);
saveObservable$.pipe(
switchMap(saveMessage => from(notificationService.showNotificataion(saveMessage))),
take(1) // this will only take the first stream so we don't get memory leaks after subscribing.
).subscribe();
```

Comment: your solution would work with angular but he is asking about redux-observable ;-)

Comment: Ok but this solution actually is rxjs specific and has nothing to do with Angular.